# Reference a variable of a dataclass in a field with a default_factory

Tags: python-dataclasses

I want to reference a dataclass variable in a lambda function for a default_factory like:

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class A:
    a: float = 1
    b: List = field(default_factory = lambda: [a])
```

but it I get the error that the variable is undefined. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/unravelling-pythons-classes/#scoping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping problem. By the time the lambda function is executed, `a` isn't visible to it any more, so it doesn't know how to resolve it. See also the much simpler [examples in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) on delayed lambda execution to understand the issue.

You can fix it by binding `a` to the lambda's local scope during its creation:

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    a: float = 1
    b: List = field(default_factory = (lambda a=a: [a]))
```

Looks a bit weird, but it does the job.

Comment: Note that this only works when capturing defaulted values, and if you construct `A(123)`  then `b==[1]`, not `[123]` as some might expect. https://godbolt.org/z/8e9sTsoqn

Comment: good point, the binding happens exactly once at class-definition time, so by the time you create instances of the class there is no way to influence `b`'s default value any more. There is a good chance OP (or anyone finding this post through google) would have been better served with writing a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).